# Проверка input на пустое значение средствами css

Tags: html, css

Добрый день. Подскажите как реализовать следующую логику на css. http://prntscr.com/h61u0q 
При наведении фокусе на input текст(placeholder) поднимается вверх и уменьшает размер. При потере фокуса, текст возвращается в исходное положение, а если пользователь вводит текст в input placeholder остается на месте. 
Вопрос в том как оставить текст placeholder на верху при заполненном input?
Вот код: https://codepen.io/iliasidash/pen/WXwOMM

```css
.feedback-form {
  &__title {
    font-size: 25px;
    margin-bottom: 35px;
  }
  &__label {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    span {
      display: block;
      position: absolute;
      width: 100%;
      color: #777777;
      font-size: 15px;
      left: 0;
      bottom: 7px;
      top: 20px;
      transition: all .3s .1s;
    }
  }
  &__input {
    display: block;
    background: none;
    border: none;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #b8b6b4;
    padding: 20px 0 7px;
    width: 100%;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    top: 20px;
    &:focus {
      color: #222222;
      border-bottom: 1px solid #61574c;
    }
    &:focus+span {
      top: 0;
      font-size: 12px;
      transition: all .3s;
    }
    &:required+span {
      top: 0;
      font-size: 12px;
    }
  }
  &__btn {
    color: #c58d4c;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    margin-top: 20px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="feedback-form">
  <div class="feedback-form__title">Связаться с нами</div>
  <form action="#" method="post">
    <label class="feedback-form__label">
      <input type="text" class="feedback-form__input" name="name">
      <span>Укажите ваше имя *</span>
    </label>

    <label class="feedback-form__label">
      <input type="email" class="feedback-form__input" name="email">
      <span>Почту для обратной связи*</span>
    </label>

    <label class="feedback-form__label">
      <input type="tel" class="feedback-form__input" name="phone">
      <span>Номер телефона *</span>
    </label>
    <label class="feedback-form__label">
      <input type="tel" class="feedback-form__input" name="phone">
      <span>Ваше сообщение *</span>
    </label>

    <button type="submit" class="btn page-contacts__btn feedback-form__btn">Отправить</button>
  </form>
```

Comment: Сомневаюсь, что чистым css, это возможно...  А почему css, это принципиально?

Comment: Посмотрите на `:placeholder-shown`, но [can i use](http://caniuse.com/#search=%3Aplaceholder-shown)

Comment: .....Пишу в ответ, т.к. не хватает репутации, чтобы писать комментарий....... Посмотрите здесь - 1) https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nry8rEJuzdc 2) https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ykhb6jvGirU&t=825s мне кажется, там есть ответ на Ваш вопрос

Comment: Air, с js нет проблем. Хотел узнать есть ли возможность на css сделать

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Кроссбраузерно - никак. Либо использовать :placeholder-shown (не работает в IE и Edge) либо псевдо-класс :valid (не совсем корректно работает с input type="email". Если ввести адрес почты как положено (example@mail.com), эффект будет достигнут. Но при случайном наборе букв плейсхолдер вернется на своем место.

```css
body {
 padding: 20px;
}

label {
 position: relative;
}

#ph {
 padding: 5px;
}

.ph {
 position: absolute;
 transition: .2s;
 left: 3px;
 top: 2px;
 font-size: 14px;
}

#ph:focus ~ .ph,
#ph:valid ~ .ph {
 top: -25px;
 font-size: 12px;
}
```

```html
<label for="ph">
  <input type="text" id="ph" required>
  <span class="ph">Placeholder</span>
 </label>
```